# How to select object's DiscriminatorColumn with Eclipse Link

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have an abstract Entity User and some inherited classes, e.g. Patient that use DiscriminatorColumn as an inheritance method.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "USER_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class User {
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("patient")
public class Patient extends User {
    ...
}
```

I need to know the object's type. I found a solution for Hibernate, but I use Eclipse Link and I want to write a script that retrieves the DiscriminatorColumn from database. I tried

```
em.createQuery("SELECT u.user_type FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username", String.class)
            .setParameter("username", username)
            .getSingleResult();
```

and

```
em.createQuery("SELECT u.class FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username", String.class)
            .setParameter("username", username)
            .getSingleResult();
```

but none is working for me and I'm getting `IllegalArgumentException`

```
The state field path 'u.class' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

Is it possible in Eclipe Link?

Comment: none of those are working because they are not in the JPA spec (yes, all of this stuff is defined!). Clearly there is "TYPE" which is in the JPA spec, but that returns the class not the discriminator as such

Comment: that wouldn't be a problem I suppose, but what will it return? String? I can't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Neil Stockton I found the solution by getting the class name, not the DiscriminatorValue, but it works good enough. Using `TYPE(u)` instead of `u.class` works fine.

```
em.createQuery("SELECT TYPE(u) FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username", Class.class)
            .setParameter("username", username)
            .getSingleResult().getSimpleName();
```